# How to retrieve last log when grouped by a specific attribute in elasticsearch_dsl?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

Need to get the last log (based on timestamp) for each server using python elasticsearch_dsl

for example here are the logs:

Server     Hour   CPU%

server1   8AM     19
server1   9AM     19
server1   10AM    29
server2   8AM     19
server2   9AM     13
server2   10AM    21
server3   8AM     1
server3   9AM     11
server3   10AM    2

What I want to extract:

server1   10AM    29
server2   10AM    21
server3   10AM    2

I thought starting with something like

```
s.aggs.bucket('server_bucket','terms', field='server')
```

but I'm kind of stuck because I don't want a metric, only the last record for each server.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Got it

```
    s.aggs.bucket('server', 'terms', field='server').metric('last_log','top_hits',size = 1,_source = ["CPU_PCT","@timestamp"],  sort=[{"@timestamp": {"order": "desc"}}])
```